# Why threads are dropped off from jmeter test?

Tags: multithreading, performance, jmeter, load, throughput

Have a jmeter test set to run for 8 hours with 10 thread groups, each with different number of threads, also using throughput shaping timer with different TPS rate for each thread group; after some random time (most of the times after 6 hours) one of the thread groups terminate the active threads, I have tried different configuration along with the throughtput shaping timer like using concurrnecy thread groups and loop controllers but result is the same; this is what I see in logs:

```
2021-07-27 16:50:30,005 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary = 1142797 in 02:16:50 =  139.2/s Avg:    40 Min:    12 Max:  3621 Err:     3 (0.00%)
2021-07-27 16:51:00,001 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +   4158 in 00:00:30 =  138.6/s Avg:    39 Min:    13 Max:   228 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 312 Started: 312 Finished: 0
2021-07-27 16:51:00,002 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary = 1146955 in 02:17:20 =  139.2/s Avg:    40 Min:    12 Max:  3621 Err:     3 (0.00%)
2021-07-27 16:51:30,006 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +   4202 in 00:00:30 =  140.0/s Avg:    39 Min:    13 Max:   214 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 312 Started: 312 Finished: 0
2021-07-27 16:51:30,007 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary = 1151157 in 02:17:50 =  139.2/s Avg:    40 Min:    12 Max:  3621 Err:     3 (0.00%)
2021-07-27 16:52:00,003 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +   4181 in 00:00:30 =  139.4/s Avg:    40 Min:    13 Max:   209 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 312 Started: 312 Finished: 0
2021-07-27 16:52:00,003 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary = 1155338 in 02:18:20 =  139.2/s Avg:    40 Min:    12 Max:  3621 Err:     3 (0.00%)
2021-07-27 16:52:13,010 INFO k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: No further RPS schedule, asking threads to stop...
2021-07-27 16:52:13,011 INFO k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: Stopping gracefuly threads of Thread Group : 05_GET_GetEligibleRewards_GeoAtts
```

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> VariableThroughputTimer: No further RPS schedule, asking threads to stop...

This line means that you're using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) and its "Duration" exceeded:

[image]

No matter what you set in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [derivative](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) your test will end when the Throughput Shaping Timer ends so make sure to set the "Duration" in the Throughput Shaping Timer(s) to be equal to the desired duration of your test

Comment: Thanks for your reponse; I have a Variable called "duration" along with others fo the scenario configuration, and I'm using the same in the Trhead Group duration and in the Throughput Shaping Timer, in the last one I'm passing it as a property as it cannot be passed as the "normal" variable, the threads that drops during the test are not always from same thread group, also, it happens at different elapsed times, kind of frustrating.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behaviour, have the same shared variable. I even have two thread groups with a throughput shaping timer defined (with the exact same length) and just one of them is saying `No further RPS schedule, asking threads to stop`. 

Did you ever find a solution?