# Jmeter Test abruptly terminates

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

My jmeter tests abruptly terminated and the timings were random. It’s exactly same as below issue. We have checked all the throughput shaping timer durations and they are fine. Can someone suggest me solution for below. We are running these tests through Linux.

[Why threads are dropped off from jmeter test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552482/why-threads-are-dropped-off-from-jmeter-test)

Comment: Post your logs and .jmx

Answer (score 0):

In case if "It’s exactly same as below issue" you need to follow steps from the exactly same as below answer.

The "tests abruptly terminated and the timings were random" most probably indicates that your JMeter load generator is overloaded and cannot conduct the required load.

Make sure to:

1. Follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Ensure that JMeter machine has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. It can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
3. If one machine is not enough for creating the required load you might need to consider [JMeter Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)